# Bat file arguments Conflict?

Tags: batch-file, parameters, window, arguments

I am new to bat files.
I try to call a function with 2 arguments like this:

```
How I run the bat in my local machine 
c:\remote.bat pass1 pass2 pass3 pass4
=============================================================================
inside remote.bat

call:ECHOPATH %ip% log

:ECHOPATH
echo .\%1Server_Report\%2
```

However the problem is that this bat file is located at a remote machine, and when I called it from my local machine, I actually passed 4 arguments too. 
Now the  %1 and %2 is recognized as those I passed in when I called the bat file, not the function.
My aim is that I can passed different arguments when executing the bat file and another set of arugment when calling a function inside that bat file. 
Call I get some help please ? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the batch file is coded, your problem is that there is nothing preventing the execution to enter the subroutine after the first call. That is, the function is called, two arguments passed and used, the subrotine ends, execution continues after the call and the code after the label is executed again, this time without the call, so, the arguments `%1`, `%2` are now a reference to the batch file arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Sorry, I am not very clear about the whole execution process of a bat file. How can I prevent the execution to enter the subroutine after the first call ? Should i set it to null before I call the label ?And if yes, what is the syntax to set %1 to null?

Comment: I set them to null by set "%1="set "%2=" before the call and now it works as the way I want. Thanks

Comment: @LuisLiu, the easiest way to prevent the execution to enter into the subroutine when not intended is place an `exit /b` or and `goto :eof` before the `:echopath` or at the end of the main line of execution (usually both places are the same)